# DLHR differential pressure sensor SPI

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, sensors, spi

I am new to using SPI with an Arduino. But I'm trying to wrap my head around the "coding protocols"/syntax of the Arduino IDE code. I understand the basics of how SPI works conceptually, just not how to actually use it with an Arduino Mega 2560. Most examples on YouTube are about how to play with LEDs and the examples on the Arduino blogs are very specific for two specific examples.
Analog reading is incredibly easy (which is what I am used to doing).

I have an AllSensors DLHR-L05D 18 bit differential pressure sensor (SPI, not I2C) [Datasheet: https://www.allsensors.com/cad/DS-0350_Rev_B.PDF]. Page 5 has the commands needed. From my understanding, I need to somehow send from the Arduino to the sensor a "start" sequence (0xAA) and a "read" (0xF0 and 0x00) sequence, but I'm not sure what that looks like when coding it.

Any and all advice/direction on how to "code up" this SPI device would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’d suggest finding one of the Adafruit sensors that uses SPI, and read source code of the library they provide for that sensor.

Comment: By any chance, are you planning to use this to measure static pressure between the return and supply of a HVAC system? If you are, I'm curious... do you just connect a few feet of plastic tubing (like you'd use for an aquarium air hose) to each barb, drill a small hole in the two ducts, shove a tube into each, and seal up around the tubes? Or do you need something specific on the duct side of the tube, like a metal tube of some kind? I know that for measuring atmospheric pressure, almost anything will do... but suspect distinguishing between 0.5" WC and 0.6" WC is a bit more demanding...

Comment: I'm using this sensor to measure atmospheric pressure differences in a moving object (i.e., using it for a pseudo-pitot-static system), so I am using plastic pitot tubes typically used in remote control aircraft. The data sheet says that this sensor is typically used in HVACs, but I haven't tried it in my HVAC per se.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, someone actually has a specific library to handle the I2C for this sensor, which helps tremendously: https://github.com/jeremycole/AllSensors_DLHR